# Inheritance method calling - Java

Tags: java, variables, inheritance, methods

I have a method in a class that sets "Position X" and "Position Y".

```
public class Player {

    int positionX, postinionY;

    public void setPosition (int position_X, int position_Y)
    {
         positionX = position_X;
         postinionY = position_Y;
    }

}
```

I have another class "World" that has an array in it called grid. I have to use the values of position x and y from Player to get location from the grid.

```
public class World extends Player {
    int [] [] grid = new int [16] [16];

    public int getLocationID (int x, int y)
    {
        return grid [x][y];
    }
}
```

I need help to take Position x,y(Player) and use them instead x,y (World)

Comment: What do you mean? And what is the logic behind World inheriting Player??

Answer (score 5):

You could add another method to `World` get the own (the players) location id:

```
public int getPlayerLocationID() {
    return grid[positionX][positionY];
}
```

But - honestly - in what kind of universum we have a relation "a world **is-a** player"? In all universums that I know (Ok, only one, actually), we usually have "a world **has-many** players".

Answer (score 0):

This method should do what you want.

```
public class World extends Player {
    int [] [] grid = new int [16] [16];
    public int getPlayerID (int locationX, int locationY)
    {
        if((locationX>15)||(locationX>16))
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Player locations should be less than 16!");
        return grid [locationX][locationY];
    }
}
```

Note that it will throw an exception in case the arguments provided are not valid.